# Resolvent of maximal-monotone operator

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, banach-spaces, duality-theorems, monotone-operator-theory

I'm reading Barbus & Precupanu's 'Convexity and optimization in Banach spaces'. The authors define what I think is the resolvent for an operator $A: X \to X^*$ (or subset $A \subset X \times X^*$) where $X^*$ is the dual space:

> Let $ X,X^*$ be reflexive and strictly convex and $A$ maximal monotone and $F$ the duality mapping ($F = \{ x^*: (x,x^*) = \lVert x \rVert^2 =  \lVert x^* \rVert^2$) . Then the equation
>    $$ 0 \in F(y-x) + \lambda Ay$$
>   has a unique solution $x_\lambda$.

The maximal monotonicity follows since $F$ is also a maximal monotone operator and demicontinuous (since $X^*$ is strictly convex ) I think.

The authors then claim that the uniqueness follows from the fact that $X$ and $X^*$ are strictly convex and the inequality:

$$ (F(x) -F(y), x-y) \geq \left( \lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert \right)^2$$.

I wonder if anyone can help me and explain how the uniqueness follows from this?

Kind regards and thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you try using Cauchy Schwarz inequality?

Comment: No, in what way?

Comment: Consider $| (F(x) -F(y), x-y) |=|\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-(F(x),y)-(F(y),x)|.$

Comment: I'm sorry, don't understand. How do you use this to show uniqueness?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question. Are you stuck in proving the last inequality or how uniqueness follows from the inequality?

Comment: Aha I see, I meant how uniqueness follows from the inequality (I will edit and clarify this).

Comment: strict convexity is usually the culprit behind uniqueness.